# Should input checkbox outline include margins or not?

Tags: html, css

Input checkbox outline in Chrome behaves itself really odd.

Generally, outline doesn't include margins, but when you set the focus on it with the keyboard (! not the mouse), it starts including margins. For the tag types other than input (as well, as for the other input type) everything works fine (outline never includes margins). In Firefox everything works fine as well.

Here is the JsFiddle to test this:

```css
.error input {
  outline: 2px solid #c00;
  margin: 2px;
}

.error input[type=checkbox] {
  outline: 2px solid #c00;
}
```

```html
<div class="error">
  <input type='checkbox'><label>Some label</label>
  <input type='text'>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/71ybetjv/

Is this a Chrome bug? And is there any workaround for that?

Comment: That's something good for accessibility, don't try to override it. When using a keyboard we need a clear indication that we have a focus otherwise it's difficult to navigate if we don't have one

Comment: The thing is, that the input box gets the focus also after a mouse click (and this "mouse" focus is no different from the "keyboard" focus), so I don't understand why they should look different.

Comment: they are totally different. Using a mouse you see the cursor on the screen so you already have an indication where you are clicking. When using a keyboard you don't have any cursor, you jump between elements so you need to know on which element you are

Comment: I know that. But after you click on the input with a mouse, this input gets the focus (i.e jumping starts from it, it consumes key presses and so on), and this focus is no different from the focus that you get while jumping. I mean that this focuses (after they are set) are totally the same (you know, the duck test, and all that) and thus should appear the same.

Comment: I am not here to convince you but to give you facts. :focus-visible was created to make both focus different and it was something needed that's why such selector was created: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#the-focus-visible-pseudo
You want them to be the same because you never faced any situation where we need to differentiate between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chromes default `:focus-visible` style contains `outline-offset: 2px;`.

This can be overwritten: (Though it's worth noting that you should replace it with another clear "focused" style for accessibility)

```css
.error input {
  outline: 2px solid #c00;
  margin: 2px;
}
.error input:focus-visible {
  outline-offset: 0;
}
.error input[type=checkbox] {
  outline: 2px solid #c00;
}
```

```html
<div class="error">
  <input type='checkbox'><label>Some label</label><br />
  <input type='text' />
</div>
```